# Linq query in next line

Tags: c#, linq

Why line 2 of mycode can not be read :

```
var allResarchs = db.Researchs;
allResarchs.Where(a => a.ChiefManagerId == 1);
allResarchs.ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can not be read"? Do you get an error or is the behavior not what you expect?

Comment: You'll probably want to re-assign the returned value of the `Where()` method into `allResarchs` variable: `allResarchs = allResarchs.Where(a => a.ChiefManagerId == 1);`

Comment: `var allResarchs =db.Researchs.Where(a => a.ChiefManagerId == 1).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linq never changes the input sequence!**

```
allResearches.Where(research => research.ChiefManagerId == 1);
```

This statement won't change allResearches. You could do the following. (by the way, I've changed the `var` into the actual returned types, so you understand better what is going on.)

```
IQueryable<Research> queryResearches = db.Researches;
IQueryable<Research> queryResearchesWithId1 = queryResearches
    .Where(research => research.ChiefManagerId == 1);
List<Research> researchesWithId1 = queryResearchedWithId1.ToList();
```

Be aware, that until the last statement the query is not executed, there is no communication with the database yet. Only the last statement will actually contact the database.

Of course you can write it all in one statement. However, this won't improve performance very much:

```
var researchesWithId1 = db.Researches
    .Where(research => research.ChiefManagerId == 1)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You never set the value of Where statement to the variable.

`var allResarchs = db.Researchs.Where(a => a.ChiefManagerId == 1).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

You should assign results of `LINQ` queries:

```
var allResarchs = db.Researchs;
var filtered = allResarchs.Where(a => a.ChiefManagerId == 1);
var list = filtered.ToList();
```

Also you can do it in simplier way (if you do not need intermediate results):

```
var list = db.Researchs.Where(a => a.ChiefManagerId == 1).ToList();
```